# Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined in gulp-browserify

Tags: json, angularjs, node.js, gulp, browserify

i am running into a problem. I have created my own seed: https://github.com/damirkusar/leptir-angular-seed with gulp, browserify and more.

Everything worked fine, since i had the good idea to update node from 10.32 to 12.5, i am getting the below error. I think that this is since then. I tried it also on a different machine, same setup, same error.

so, after npm install and bower install i am starting the app with:

```
gulp
```

or when trying to build the project with

```
gulp build
```

i am getting this error:

```
leptir-angular-seed/node_modules/gulp-browserify/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/module-deps/index.js:162
rs.on('error', function (err) { tr.emit('error', err) });
                                  ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined
at ReadStream.<anonymous> (/leptir-angular-seed/node_modules/gulp-browserify/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/module-deps/index.js:162:39)
at ReadStream.emit (events.js:107:17)
at fs.js:1618:12
at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:95:15)
```

Here is also the link to the package.json: https://github.com/damirkusar/leptir-angular-seed/blob/450ffe99943036cd5a670e54ec3884c02bd7bb8a/package.json.

but luckily, karma start executes the tests and all tests are passing..

Maybe some versions are not really supported correctly? 
Does anybody have an idea what causes this problem?

-- edit 2015-June-25 14:23

I am using the module which cause the problem in my gulp file like this:

```
// Browserify task
gulp.task('browserify', function () {
gulp.src(paths.browserify[0])
    .pipe(browserify({
        insertGlobals: true,
        debug: true
    }))
    // Bundle to a single file
    .pipe(concat('bower.js'))
    // Output it to our dist folder
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.destination_public))
    .pipe(refresh(lrServer)); // Tell the lrServer to refresh;

gulp.src(paths.browserify[1])
    .pipe(browserify({
        insertGlobals: true,
        debug: true
    }))
    // Bundle to a single file
    .pipe(concat('app.js'))
    // Output it to our dist folder
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.destination_public))
    .pipe(refresh(lrServer)); // Tell the lrServer to refresh;
});
```

which browserifyies these app.js file and its content:

```
require('./modules/core');
require('./modules/core');
```

and bower.js with its content:

```
'use strict';

require('jquery');
require('bootstrap');
require('moment');
require('underscore');
require('angular');
require('angular-animate');
require('angular-bootstrap');
require('angular-bootstrap-tpls');
require('angular-cookies');
require('angular-mocks');
require('angular-resource');
require('angular-ui-router');
require('angular-ui-utils');
require('angular-translate');
require('angular-translate-loader-static-files');
require('angular-translate-loader-url');
require('angular-translate-storage-cookie');
require('angular-translate-storage-local');
```

thank you so much

Comment: what should `tr` be? the error normally means, that you have a syntactic or semantic error in your code.

Comment: hmm.. i dont know what tr should be.. its in the browsery module a guess.. its not my code.. i do not have such a code.. could it be that there is an error in the browserify module which gulp-browserify depends on?

Comment: I am pretty sure, that that causes the error. But i have to see more code to help you. And i should now, what `tr` should be...

Comment: all my code is here: https://github.com/damirkusar/leptir-angular-seed

Comment: the project is too complex to see the relevant code. pls make a list of the relevant files or add their code (relevant parts only) to your question.

Comment: i added some more infos.. not sure what i really should share.. shared now how i use this npm module.. adding just files so that i have just one app.js file with all my javascript codes needed.. but in fact, otherwise i am not using this module which causes the error..

Comment: oooh my goood.. i solved the problem.. a really really bad mistake :( but must say that the error message is not really helpful. I installed it on my companies computer and there i got a different error message which pointed me to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a windows machine (instead of mine mac) it showed me a better error message.

I referenced bower packages which where not installed.. but totally forgot to remove it from package.json and bower.js.

so i removed code in the above files which referenced the following packages:

- angular-translate-storage-cookie
- angular-translate-storage-local

-- UPDATE 27th June 2015 - 22:41 --

I saw that gulp-browserify is blacklisted by gulpjs, so i thought its better to get rid of it, because i faced also problems on windows machines. Instead of using gulp-browserify, i am using plain browserify with vinyl-transform.

First, update your package.json with this:

```
"browserify": "9.0.4",
"vinyl-transform": "1.0.0"
```

You see, that i am using exactly these two versions, this is because with newer browserify versions, things are not really working, so to be sure that it works also when i update my packages, i keep them in this versions.

Then lets update our gulp file. We will need to add these two lines:

```
var browserify = require('browserify'),
transform = require('vinyl-transform');
```

and my new task looks like this:

```
gulp.task('browserify', function () {
  var browserified = transform(function(filename) {
    var b = browserify(filename);
    return b.bundle();
  });

  return gulp.src(paths.browserify)
    .pipe(browserified)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.destination_public));
});
```

its now shorter and much cleaner. My paths are configured like this..

```
var paths = {
    ...
    browserify: ['./public/bower.js', './public/app.js'],
    ...
    destination_public: './dist/'
};
```

now my seed is working on mac and windows the same way. 
https://github.com/damirkusar/leptir-angular-seed

Answer (score 2):

`"...but in fact, otherwise i am not using this module which causes the error."` - *damir*

modules has dependencies too. it seems to be a problem with one of these modules that are used by an other module.

It could be possible that a module you are using has a dependency on a node component of the old version. Try to get the old back until the bug is fixed.

Comment: Hi Marcel, i downgraded my node to 10.32, my npm to 1.4.28, also moved some packages to older versions regarding the older commits, and still same problem.. if i am not asking to much, can you clone the repo, and install the node packages and bower and run the app with the command gulp? just to see if it is working on your machine? :) if yes, then someting is wrong on my machines.. if not, then i don't know anymore